Improving a logistic regression where multiple signals separately yield the same accuracy, and combining them does not improve the model
I have a logistic regression that estimates the probability of an event occurring. There are roughly 10,000 data-points, and I have roughly 20 model features. The model features are each quite different; their pairwise correlations lie roughly in the range [-0.5, 0.5].
If I model a logistic regression with each of the 20 features individually, I get an accuracy of around 64-66% for 15 of them, with similar BCEs. For the other 5, the accuracy of the individual model is lower.
When I combine all 20 features into one model, the accuracy and BCE does not improve.
This is counterintuitive to me- I would expect that combining the features into a larger model would improve the accuracy, due to interactions between the features or the ability to create a more precise 'filter' (e.g. if two features both imply the event should occur). I've also tried more complex models e.g. neural networks or CART-based models, but the accuracy still does not improve.
I wonder what the root explanation might be, how I might debug further, and what steps I might take to attempt to improve my model?

(1) What is BCE? (2) Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models? (3) Interactions may simply not be relevant, and/or your features may indeed be redundant - pairwise correlations only tell part of the story, try a PCA. (4) An alternative would be to not build one large model, but to combine the (probabilistic, see that link) predictions from the smaller models.

logistic regression will not automatically look at interactions but only discount correlations.  I would advise therefore to expand your input to products of  pairs of features and see if any improvement occurs.

@StephanKolassa: (1) BCE = Binary Cross Entropy--I was using 0.5 as my cutoff threshold (2) Interesting suggestion - will look at instead using confidence! (3) noted, will try regression on PCA components to see if I get interesting results. (4) For the probabilistic predictions from smaller models, would you suggest combining them independently, or also estimating some sort of covariance between model confidence intervals?
Thank you for your input!

@seanv507: thanks for your suggestion! I'll start with pairwise features and see if that gets me anywhere.

Entropy is good, it's essentially the log score, which is a proper scoring rule, see here. I would recommend you think critically about that hard 0.5 threshold, see here. For combination, I would start with a simple unweighted average of probabilistic predictions. It's often surprisingly hard to beat this (the "forecast combination puzzle").
